# hide a text at the end of the animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, transition

```
 .title2 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 31%;
   animation-name: fadeOutOpacity;
   animation-iteration-count: 1;
   animation-delay: 2.5s;
   animation-timing-function: ease-out;
   animation-duration: 1s;
 }
 @keyframes fadeOutOpacity {
   0% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   90% {
     opacity: 0;
   }
   100% {
     display: none;
   }
 }
```

Could someone explain to me how I can make it disappear? I thought so it worked but it doesn't work! I wanted to make a text disappear, the effect works but then the text comes back visible when instead I would like to hide it permanently at the end of the animation.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS property [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode), and change your Keyframe Animation like so:

```
.title2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 31%;
  animation-name: fadeOutOpacity;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOutOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you even toggle the display property from none to block, your transition on other elements will not occur. It's work only with displayed elements. If u want to hide element u can use `opacity`, `height`

```css
.title2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 31%;
   animation: 1s fadeOutOpacity ease-out;
   opacity: 0
 }
 @keyframes fadeOutOpacity {
   0% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   100% {
     opacity: 0;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="title2"/>
```